# What's the difference between PCIe linkup and card present?

Tags: pcie

In linux log, I can see link up and Card present, these two kinds of messages.

What's their difference?

Card present means only detected the device but no link up ( device still can't be used? ), ex:

```
pcieport 0000:b2:00.0: pciehp: Slot(18): Card present
```

link up means the device is working?

```
pcieport 0000:b2:00.0: pciehp: Slot(18): Link Up
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, one says "I've detected there's a card", and the second is "I've successfully established a way of talking to it". That's what we can infer directly from the wording!

If you want to understand the software conditions that need to be met for either, [Linux is open source, you can read the source that emits these kernel logs](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9-rc6/source/drivers/pci/hotplug/pciehp_ctrl.c#L273)

Hardware-wise, in PCIe, detection and link upbring are simply two different things, and the logs reflect that. That's like finding a person (detection) and talking to him (establishing a link) are two different things.

> link up means the device is working?

No, it means the link is up. That's necessary, not sufficient.